# Split user input into string, then compare the list to a pre-defined dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I'm currently junking around with randomization and have stumbled onto a roadblock of sorts...I've made two lists, one of letters a-z and another of numbers 1-26. I shuffle both lists then combine them into a dictionary, print the dictionary to observe the results and afterwards I want to record user input, store it as a lists, then assign each letter of the user input to the value represented within the dictionary.

My code is probably a mess, but it seems to accomplish what I want up until the roadblock. Any tips or tricks?

```
import random
import secrets
alpha = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
num = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26]
random.shuffle(alpha)
random.shuffle(num)
beta = dict(zip(alpha,num))
random.shuffle(alpha)
random.shuffle(num)
delta = dict(zip(alpha,num))
print(beta)
print(delta)
userinput = input("input ")
print(userinput)
useroutput = list(userinput)
print(useroutput)
```

Comment: You mean like `useroutput = [beta.get(c, c) for c in userinput]`

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm very fresh to Python and programming in general. Is .join() used to search for matching elements within the beta list? How exactly would .join fit into my code?

Comment: I updated my comment to a list comprehension. `''.join()` is used to join a list of characters into a string - which on further examination wasn't appropriate for your question. `beta.get(c, c)` will return the value in the dictionary (or `c` if doesn't exist).

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks for the pointer, I really appreciate the help.